# Constrain animation within Grid

Tags: wpf, animation

I have a project that is WPF4 (with vb.net behind). I have a window that is full screen, and in the center of it is a grid that is constrained to 640x480 in size. I have five images animated, and the animation should take them off the grid and out of sight. However, the animation shows the image when off the grid (over the window itself.) How do I contrain my animations to stay ONLY inside of the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Grid.ClipToBounds = true;
```

That should clip the contents within the `Grid` as it moves past the bounds of the `Grid`.